# Looping parts of audio with gstreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer

I'm developing a sort of a "advanced playback" audio application to aid music transcription. The idea is to allow the user to change the audio tempo/pitch, as well as select and possibly loop parts of the audio track. I've opted to use gstreamer for the time being. I have the scaletempo plugin in the pipeline to aid with changing the tempo. I am unsure as to what's the best way to do the looping.

From reading the docs it seems that I could get it done by performing a gst_element_seek on the scaletempo element and setting the *stop_type* and *stop* parameters, waiting for an EOS on the message bus, and then performing yet another seek etc.

Is there a better way to do it? Ideally I'd like to get smooth looping, though it's not a dealbreaker if I don't. The gstreamer docs contain mentions of a concept of "segments", but from glancing at the docs I still don't have any idea what they are or whether they're useful in my scenario.

Pointers to code in C/Python/Haskell/whatever are very much welcome.

Comment: Just a thought: from a UX standpoint, you may not want "smooth" looping. Obviously, you'll want to get rid of clicks at playback start/stop boundaries, but a little silence might actually help in the case of transcription. Having imperfect loop points (which is what will usually happen) is awkward and a little silence between loops might actually help the listener orient themselves musically at the start of each loop.

Comment: Hm, I haven't thought about that. My motivation is that I personally often (ab)use transcription software for practicing a passage, where smooth looping definitely helps.

Comment: And I didn't mean to say it's wouldn't be nice to be ABLE to do smooth looping. Sorry I don't have a clue about gstreamer, though.